# Get page name from NavigatingFromEventArgs in MAUI

Tags: android, ios, .net, maui

How do I extract the destination page name from  `args` in .net MAUI:

```
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingFromEventArgs args)
```

Comment: Looking at the [code of the `NavigatingFromEventArgs`](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/Page/NavigatingFromEventArgs.cs) class, there is nothing you can extract from it as it doesn't define any additional properties.

Comment: What is your goal (why do you want that page name)? If you are trying to "intercept" the navigation, go somewhere different, I don't think that is a concept in Maui.